# Webview in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I want a small UIWebView on a navigation bar. Is it possible since NavigationBar takes only UINavigationItem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `UIWebView` actually showing on the `UINavigationBar`, you can set the [`UINavigationItem.titleView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView) property to point to it.

If you want to show the UIWebView on the screen when a new navigation item is pushed on the navigation bar, then you should be [using the navigation bar with an `UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW14).